# Can't add anything correctly to useState array?

Tags: reactjs, state

I'm new in React. I writed that code by following a tutorial.
I tried many ways but couldn't add new arrays correctly into useState array.

```
function TodoApp(){

  const [liste, setListe] = useState( [] );

  function listeyeEkle(e) {

    console.log(e); // {yazi: "First", id: 0}   It's great here, no problems.

    setListe( [e, ...liste] ) // Console log in Picture 1

    setListe( e ); // Console log in Picture 2

    console.log(liste);

  }
```

[Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKGm8.png)
[Picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBJhC.png)

Something going wrong and it's adding a empty object into array??

Do you have any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you running `setListe` twice?

Comment: `setListe( [e, ...liste] )` is the correct variant. I think the issue you're running into is that `setListe` is asynchronous, so you won't be able to `console.log` the new array immediately. But it will be available next render.

Comment: @Nick nope, tried them separately. Also, you were right. It's working with correct variant. But it still adding empty and undefined objects.. Do you have a idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you wrote it, you are setting the correct array first:

```
setListe( [e, ...liste] )
```

Afterwards you are setting the state to the value of the inputs element:

```
setListe( e )
```

I think you should remove this line? Then it will work! But might not show up in console.log(liste), due to the async nature of setState()!